# Always getting a 403 response from curseforge.com (python)

Tags: python, python-requests

**main.py**

```
import requests

link = 'https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/jei'
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'
    }

req = requests.get(link, headers=header)
print(req)
```

I have tried adding the 'referer' field but it still gives me a 403 response, I even tried using requests.Session() but that didn't work too, maybe the server needs some specific field to accept the request? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Because that websites uses captcha to prevent non-humans to access the website. You can see the captcha page by saving the result of the request in a file and then opening it in a browser:

```py
from requests import get

result = get("https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/jei")

with open("temp.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(result.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it by adding this to the url**

```
'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:'
```